# GIMP: Lock layers to be identical

Tags: gimp, layers, layer-composition

I have a file I'm setting up to essentially split a background image into three parts which I can apply transformations to independently; I'm doing this by setting up three layer groups, each of which has the same base image but applies a different clipping mask. I expect to want to use this on a number of separate background images which have the same general format, so it would be nice to make the fact that the three background images are the same a specified invariant rather than doing it by hand. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. You can paste new images into GIMP and Anchor them to the active layer - this won't affect the layer masks. Further than than, what you are describing  as a "specified invariant" sounds like the use of Smart Objects in Photoshop. These aren't available in GIMP unfortunately. However Krita (which is free and Open Source) has something similar called [File Layers](https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/layers_and_masks/file_layers.html). You might want to take a look.

Comment: Not new, just too jaded to use a persistent account on any SE site given the toxic community dynamics its structure fosters.

Answer (score -2):

my dear friend, Stack Overflow user, although I do not understand your problem well, and I hope you will give me a more description of the problem, but I think that you mean or that you want to move each of the background parts separately. If you want to do this, you can open the background in three different times each time You select the part from the background and perform a Select and Mask, then you create one file for your design and put them all in it, my dear friend, and so you can modify them all separately, my friend, with ease and simplicity, my friend. Tell me, my dear friend, if this is your problem, my dear friend. It was not your problem, so please, a detailed explanation of the problem, my friend, so that I can help you more, my dear friend.
Thanks and goodbye